# Criar pasta php dentro de uma outra pasta

Tags: php, laravel

Estou dando manutenção em um projeto feito em laravel,
onde os arquivos do objeto é salvo neste caminho ,arquivos pdf

**C:\xamp2\htdocs\pmo\public\projetos_arquivos**

O trecho de código onde salva os arquivos é este

```
public function salvar($objArquivo, $objProjeto, $objDataAtualizacao) {
    $strCaminho = public_path('projetos_arquivos') . '\\' . $objProjeto->codigo; // 'public\projetos_arquivos\codigo_projeto'
    $strNome = $objProjeto->codigo . "_" . $objDataAtualizacao->format("d-m-Y"); // Nomeia arquivo com codigo do projeto + data passada como argumento

    if(!file_exists($strCaminho)) { // Cria pasta para o projeto, caso não já exista uma
        $objProjetoDiretorio = File::makeDirectory($strCaminho);
    }

    $objArquivo->move($strCaminho, $strNome . ".pdf"); // Salvando arquivo no servidor
    $strCaminhoArquivo = $strCaminho . "\\" . $strNome . ".pdf";
    return($strCaminhoArquivo);
}
```

Quando salvo um novo objeto com o mesmo nome que já existe nesta página ,o novo objeto pega os arquivos do objeto que já existe .

como faço pra salvar o arquivo em outra pasta?? e exibir os arquivos desta nova pasta e a antiga ??

o meu listar estar assim

```
public function listarArquivos($strCodigoProjeto, $intQuantidade) {
    $strCaminho = public_path() . "\\projetos_arquivos\\" . $strCodigoProjeto. "\\*";
    //$strCaminho2 = asset("projetos_arquivos/" . $strCodigoProjeto);
    //var_dump($strCaminho);exit();
    $arrArquivos = File::glob($strCaminho);
```

gostaria de uma luz aew...quando chego a criar uma nova pasta os dados da outra não lista

Comment: [Para criar diretório utilize isso](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mkdir.php)

Answer (score 0):

Coloca um else no !file_exists, pra que, se existir, ele criar um novo ao invés de dar um update no antigo.

Por exemplo:

```
if(!file_exists($strCaminho)) { 
   $objProjetoDiretorio = File::makeDirectory($strCaminho);
} else {
   $objProjetoDiretorio = File::makeDirectory($strCaminho . md5($strCaminho));
}
```

Comment: eu fiz conforme o exemplo e cria o novo projeto ,só que na hora de listar o novo objeto ele exibe os arquivos do objeto que já existia antes tipo criei um objeto ITC01 com 10 arquivos pdf dentro desta pasta, se eu criar um novo objeto ITC01 ele cria o novo mas os arquivos ele exibe o do antigo.. entendeu ?

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz assim pela lógica acho que também estar válido correto??
O meu salvar neste mesmo caminho criei uma nova pasta com o nome de *projetos_arquivos08* e neste mesmo lugar tem a pasta projetos_arquivos...

```
public function salvar($objArquivo, $objProjeto, $objDataAtualizacao) {
   // $strCaminho = public_path('projetos_arquivos') . '\\' . $objProjeto->codigo; // 'public\projetos_arquivos\codigo_projeto'
    $strCaminho2 = public_path('projetos_arquivos08') . '\\' . $objProjeto->codigo;//pode criar só na gri2018

    $strNome = $objProjeto->codigo . "_" . $objDataAtualizacao->format("d-m-Y"); // Nomeia arquivo com codigo do projeto + data passada como argumento
    
    if(!file_exists($strCaminho2)) { // Cria pasta para o projeto, caso não já exista uma
        $objProjetoDiretorio = File::makeDirectory($strCaminho2);
    }
    
    $objArquivo->move($strCaminho, $strNome . ".pdf"); // Salvando arquivo no servidor
    $strCaminhoArquivo = $strCaminho . "\\" . $strNome . ".pdf";
    return($strCaminhoArquivo);
}
```

O meu listar ficou assim

```
public function listarArquivos($strCodigoProjeto, $intQuantidade) {
    $strCaminho = public_path() . "\\projetos_arquivos\\" . $strCodigoProjeto . "\\*";
    $strCaminho2 = public_path() . "\\projetos_arquivos08\\" . $strCodigoProjeto . "\\*";
    
    //$strCaminho2 = asset("projetos_arquivos/" . $strCodigoProjeto);
    //var_dump($strCaminho);exit();
    $arrArquivos = File::glob($strCaminho, $strCaminho2);
    $arrArquivosOrganizados = array();
```

Onde dá pra pegar os arquivos da pasta

**$strCaminho = public_path() . "\projetos_arquivos\"**  e

$strCaminho2 = public_path() . "\projetos_arquivos08\" . $strCodigoProjeto . "\*";

e depois peço para a variavel $arrArquivos receber = File::glob($strCaminho, $strCaminho2); fiz certo??

Não estou podendo testar.. agora